# Unauthorized connection for super-user: hcat" when trying to query Hive through WebHCat

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I'm trying to execute a Hive query using WebHCat / Templeton.  I POST my query to /templeton/v1/hive with the "execute" parameter set equal to my query (a simple "select count(*)" query for now).

But when I do this, I always get back this error:

```
{"error":"Unauthorized connection for super-user: hcat from IP 172.31.27.207"}
```

From what I've been able to find so far, it seems that these "unauthorized connection for super-user" errors are usually to do with the proxyuser settings, so I added the following to my core-site.xml:

```
 <property> 
   <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hcat.hosts</name> 
   <value>*</value> 
 </property> 

 <property> 
   <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hcat.groups</name> 
   <value>*</value> 
 </property>
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to have helped at all.  After adding this and restarting services, I still get the same error.

I've also confirmed that all of the settings referenced here - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+InstallWebHCat

are set as listed under the section on enabling proxy users.

This is what I see in the webhcat log when I try a query:

```
WARN  | 17 Mar 2016 19:07:04,977 | org.apache.hive.hcatalog.templeton.Main | user.name is sent as form parameter which is deprecated as of Hive 0.13.  Should send it in the query string.
WARN  | 17 Mar 2016 19:07:04,977 | org.apache.hive.hcatalog.templeton.Main | user.name is sent as form parameter which is deprecated as of Hive 0.13.  Should send it in the query string.
WARN  | 17 Mar 2016 19:07:04,977 | org.apache.hive.hcatalog.templeton.Main | user.name is sent as form parameter which is deprecated as of Hive 0.13.  Should send it in the query string.
INFO  | 17 Mar 2016 19:07:05,064 | org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl | Timeline service address: http://ip-172-31-27-207.ec2.internal:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
INFO  | 17 Mar 2016 19:07:05,064 | org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy | Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-27-207.ec2.internal/172.31.27.207:8050
INFO  | 17 Mar 2016 19:07:05,229 | org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl | Timeline service address: http://ip-172-31-27-207.ec2.internal:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
INFO  | 17 Mar 2016 19:07:05,229 | org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy | Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-27-207.ec2.internal/172.31.27.207:8050
INFO  | 17 Mar 2016 19:07:05,305 | org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl | Timeline service address: http://ip-172-31-27-207.ec2.internal:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
INFO  | 17 Mar 2016 19:07:05,305 | org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy | Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-27-207.ec2.internal/172.31.27.207:8050
ERROR | 17 Mar 2016 19:07:05,315 | org.apache.hive.hcatalog.templeton.CatchallExceptionMapper | Unauthorized connection for super-user: hcat from IP 172.31.27.207
```

Any ides on what else could cause this, and how to resolve it?

Comment: There seem to be some more settings as per -http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Hive+User+Impersonation , apart from what you mentioned here. Not sure if you have all of them covered.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this is solved. Here's what happened. I was working in Ambari to make the config changes, and these settings are under the "HDFS" section.  After making the change, Ambari prompts you to restart affected services, so I took the option to do so.  Unfortunately, as it turns out, that was only restarting HDFS!  So the ResourceManager component, which is part of YARN (in Ambari terms) was not being restarted.  After restarting the YARN service, it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but the next guide solved me: http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.0.0/bk_ambari_views_guide/content/_setup_HDFS_proxy_user.html

You have to add the user that you are using to access to Ambari user interface not the user that throws the error. For example in my case, The error is the next:       `Unauthorized connection for super-user: root from IP 172.16.8.172` But the user I have to add is `hadoop.proxyuser.admin.hosts`.